# gorequest package : check specifically for timeout

Tags: go, gorequest

I am using the below package to make a outbound http request
https://github.com/parnurzeal/gorequest

For eg I am making a GET request like below
   res, body, errs = goReq.Get(url).End()

My question is how to figure out if there is timeout in the request.

Comment: You can do something like this ? `request := gorequest.New().Timeout(2*time.Millisecond)
resp, body, errs:= request.Get("http://example.com").End()`. You need to handle what should happen when the timeout hits.

Comment: Did you see the documentation for [setting a timeout](https://github.com/parnurzeal/gorequest#timeout)?

Comment: No I know how to set timeout. I want to detect if the request is timing out or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Timeout method [sets the dealines for dial, read, and write](https://github.com/parnurzeal/gorequest/blob/faf2e78/gorequest.go#L489), you can use [os.IsTimeout](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#IsTimeout) (all error types in the net and net/url packages implement `Timeout() bool`). Contexts are not supported by gorequest, so [context.Canceled](https://golang.org/pkg/context/#pkg-variables) doesn't have to be considered:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
    "time"

    "github.com/parnurzeal/gorequest"
)

func main() {
    s := httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
    }))

    request := gorequest.New()
    _, _, errs := request.Get(s.URL).Timeout(500 * time.Millisecond).End()

    for _, err := range errs {
        if os.IsTimeout(err) {
            log.Fatal("timeout")
        }
    }
}
```